# Reading vs Parsing a HTTP request

Tags: http, oop, server

I am reading *A philosophy of software design* book by J. Ousterhout.
In chapter 5 he mentioned the following exercise:

> “Implement one or more classes to make it easy for Web servers to receive incoming HTTP requests and send responses.”
> [image]

He then discuss a common **error** to solve the exercise:

> “Use two different classes for receiving HTTP requests; the first class read the request from the network connection into a string, and the second class parsed the string.”

> “Information leakage occurred because a HTTP request can’t be read without parsing much of the message; for example, the Content-Length header specifies the length of the request body, so the headers must be parsed in order to compute the total request length. As a result, both classes needed to understand most of the structure of HTTP requests, and parsing code was duplicated in both classes. ”

I can't understand the example because I don't have an idea about http requests. More precisely, I don't understand the meaning of `reading` and `parsing` in the sentence:

> "HTTP request can’t be read without parsing much of the message"

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

*Reading* means taking a bunch of bytes from some external source (like a network socket) and storing them in memory.

*Parsing* means breaking up that string of bytes into meaningful, domain-specific chunks so you can understand the message.

I haven't read that book, but the author's point is that you can't simply read the bytes first and then parse them, in two separate non-overlapping operations. HTTP requests can be of arbitrary size, so before you know how many bytes to read (that is, how many bytes represent a single HTTP request) you have to figure out how long the request is. You do that by reading the `Content-Length` header, and that requires parsing and understanding the message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I wondering about is 1. why one cannot read the http request without knowing the length? 2. why there is no other way to compute that length?

Comment: @SomeThoughts: 1) How do you know when to stop reading if you don't know the length of the thing you're reading? 2) *Why* is a difficult question to answer, you'd have to look into the origins of the HTTP specification. It's true that there are other ways they could have done it - [multipart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages) messages use a different mechanism, for example.

Comment: 1) for example when you have a string in a python file, you just need to write print("something") to print it. Same for all other manipulations. I can't see why we need the length to read the string :/

Comment: @SomeThoughts: A string is something that has already been read and stored in local memory. *Reading*, as defined above, is about creating that string from a external source of bytes. Sounds like you need to read about [streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computing)).